# Passing Button_Click Tag to another page WPF C#

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xmldataprovider

Hi have a button with click event & tag value binding from an XmlDataProvider;

```
<Button x:Name="Open" Tag="{Binding XPath=Id}" Content="Open" Click="OpenProject_Click" />
```

and in my xaml.cs click event code (creates new TabItem, with other page content);

```
  private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
                var ID = ((Button)sender).Tag;

                TabItem tabitem = new TabItem();
                tabitem.Header = ID;
                tabitem.Tag = ID;
                Frame tabFrame = new Frame();
                Pages.Views.View newTab = new Pages.Views.View(ID);
                tabFrame.Content = newTab;
                tabitem.Content = tabFrame;
                AppTabs.Items.Add(tabitem);
                tabitem.Focus();

    }
```

Below is my Other Page code;

```
    public partial class View : Page
{
    Object valueFromPage1;

    public View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public View(Object val)
        : this()
    {
        valueFromPage1 = val;
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(View_Loaded);

    }
    void View_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        text.Text = "Value passed from page1 is: " + valueFromPage1;
    }
}
```

Problem is that the value that appears on the other page as System.Xml.XmlElement when it need to be the ID Value (which is a number). Is there away to convert the System.Xml.XmlElement back to the button.Tag value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the value appears as `"System.Xml.XmlElement"` indicates that the Tag is an [`XmlElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It has an attribute [`InnerText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innertext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that contains its value (which should be the Id you are looking for).

```
var ID = (((Button)sender).Tag as XmlElement).InnerText;
```

Comment: @BENN1TH I'm not sure what your XML looks like, you can try using `InnerText` and `InnerHtml` properties, maybe they return the correct value.

Comment: @BENN1TH you're welcome. I edited the answer to use InnerText instead of Value.